# python udp listener not showing on process listening to ports

Tags: python, udp, ip, port, python-sockets

I have a script which listens to incoming udp packets on port 8087:

```
IP_ADDRESS = '0.0.0.0'
LISTEN_PORT = 8087

serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSock.bind((IP_ADDRESS, LISTEN_PORT))

while True:
        data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)
```

I run the script and can get data if I send packets to it.

When I do `sudo netstat -peant | grep ":8087 "` to see the process listening on this port, I don't have any results.

When I do `sudo netstat -peant | grep ":80 "` for example, I do get results of processes listening on this port.

Why is that? something wrong with the udp server code? shouldn't it listen on 8087?

Answer (score 0):

your server listens to the correct port but need proper data handling.
study below code and you will get a good understanding on this.

```
from socket import *
import string
from time import ctime

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8087
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
ssock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ssock.bind(ADDR)
ssock.listen(5)
try:
    while True:
        c = 1
        print 'Waiting for a connection...'
        csock, addr = ssock.accept()
        hostname, aliases, addresses = gethostbyaddr(addr[0])
        lip, lport = ssock.getsockname()
        print '''
Connected ...
Remote Host     : %s
Remote host IP  : %s
Remort Port     : %d
Connected time  : %s

Local IP        : %s
Local Port      : %d \n''' % (hostname , addr[0], addr[1], ctime(), lip, lport)
        while True:
            data = csock.recv(BUFSIZ)
            if data == 'q':
                break
            elif data == 'shut':
                ssock.close()
                break
            elif data == ' ':
                csock.send('Server Responce: <> \n')
                print 'srv responces: %d : <>' % c
                c += 1
            else:
                data1 = data.upper()
                csock.send('Server Responce: %s \n' % data1)
                print 'srv responces: %d : <%s>' % (c, data1)
                c += 1
        csock.close()
except:
    print 'Server socket closed !!!'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but  what is that has to do with the process not listening to the port? I need my udp server to be able to get data from "outside", and not only from localhost. the port is not showing on the listening ports list.. I don think that data handling has much to do with it

Comment: modify the code to print received data : `while True:
        data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)
        print data`  ,  and send some data to the port. it captures.